# "I find the Korean take on some western brands are made differently"

Tags: grammaticality

What is the grammatical structure of the following sentence?

> I find the Korean take on some western brands are made differently.

(source : http://www.waygook.org/index.php/topic,6517.140.html)

Is it grammatically correct? If not, which part is wrong and what changes should be made?

I am confused because after "I find", there is already a verb "take on"  but even further we have the verb "are made". I am not a native English speaker, so please understand my knowledge of grammar terminology is very lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "I find" part is actually pretty superfluous; it's just filler leading into the main point.

The "take on" part is not a verb in this case. The **Korean take** part is an object, and the preposition **on** indicates that it is modifying *some western brands*. Here you could substitute "version" for "take" and it would retain the same meaning (though you'd have to change "on" to "of").

Unfortunately, the sentence kind of falls apart halfway through, when you reach "are made differently." That part sounds weird to me.

This sentence seems to be trying to indicate that the Korean version of western brands are quite different from their originals (and the implication is that they are worse).

My best attempt at massaging this sentence into something grammatical is this:

> I find that the Korean take on some western brands is different [from the originals].

EDIT: Here's Webster's dictionary definition of "take" as a noun:

*a distinct or personal point of view, outlook, or assessment [was asked for her take on recent developments]; also :  a distinct treatment or variation [a new take on an old style]*

Comment: Nice, but adding a dictionary definition for this meaning of *take* would be an improvement.